# Why was my question on Itanium closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

I asked a question about [Why Intel dropped the Itanium](http://www.superuser.com/questions/510897/why-did-intel-drop-the-itanium) and it was well received (IMO), but was closed as "Not Constructive". Is there any reason why it would be closed?

Comment: You asked why a company dropped a product line. This is inherently subjective and argumentative, and often unrelated to the technology (a product selling poorly is sales related, and not related to computer hardware or software).

Answer (score 10):

Most questions that ask "why" a manufacturer did or did not do something are unlikely to be answered with a clear, definitive questions and foster discussions.  The answer with +14 votes was exemplary, but I assume that the closing of the question was on principle. (Good question too!)

Comment: (Didn't see Daniel's comment; basically what he said.)